# Highlight search result in Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to use the plugin datatables.highlight for my search result but it doesn't work.. can someone tell me if i'm missing something ?

I have included the files above:

```
dataTables.searchHighlight.css
jquery.highlight.js
dataTables.searchHighlight.min.js
```

and in my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var myTable = $('#dataTable').dataTable({
                dom: 'Blfrtip',
                retrieve: true,
                searchHighlight: true,
                buttons: [
                    {
                     ....
                    }    
                ]
        } );
        myTable.on( 'draw', function () {
            var body = $( myTable.table().body() );
            body.unhighlight();
            body.highlight( myTable.search() );  
        } );
....
```

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: Your code matches what is mentioned in [this post](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-10-22). Is searching/ordering work? Consider creating an example on https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: No I don't get any errors :/ and yes searching/ordering works

Comment: Try `draw.dt` instead of `draw`. Datatables namespaces its events.

Comment: **There's now a new plugin to handle search highlighting for DataTables: [datatables.mark.js](https://github.com/julmot/datatables.mark.js).**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listening for DataTable events can happen in 2 ways.

1. If you save the DataTable reference with `dataTable()`, it returns a jQuery object. Thus, when listening for events you must append the `.dt` namespace, like so `draw.dt`.
2. If you save the DataTable reference with `DataTable()`, it returns a DataTable api instance. In this case you can simply listen for `draw`. You can also listen for `draw.dt` but it's redundant.

https://jsfiddle.net/guanzo/9xs3zxcp/4/

I was having trouble with importing highlight.js so i pasted the code directly into the fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Try verifying your `included libraries links` because it works by just adding `searchHighlight: true`, you don't have to use functions to highlight results.

See this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8pyajepj/)